# Samba: variable sustitutions in smb.conf

Tags: configuration, samba

I checked [the smb.conf man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) and replaced the default **%S** (name of the current service, if any) with **%u** (username of the current service, if any) in **valid users** inside the **[homes]** section.

The change passed the **testparm** check but it did not work when I tried to connect to the shared resource from a Windows machine. So I went back to

```
valid users = %S
```

and it worked like a charm.

That said, why did **%S** work whereas **%u** did not? What is *real* the difference between these two variables? The man page is not conclusive in this regard.